# How to eliminate or reduce delay in showing a popup menu for the first time?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I have recently come to need some popup menus to be linked with multiple TTreeViewItem controls. The first time, I right click any of the TTreeViewItems, the delay in the showing of the popup is enough to make me believe that the click didn't register somehow and then it appears. All the subsequent times I click, the reaction is instantaneous.

I have to make my applications so that they are compatible and smooth even on Pentium 4s and the subsequent buit-in horsepower of their generation.

To reproduce:

1. Place a TTreeView on an empty form.
2. Add 5 or 6 TTreeViewItems.
3. Add a TPopupMenu and add a single TMenuItem to it.
4. Link the TPopupMenu with 2-3 of the TTreeViewItems.
5. Optionally add another TPopMenu with a single TMenuItem and link with the rest.
6. Run the application and right-click on any of the TTreeViewItems.

Is there a method I can call to bring the popup menu into the cache immediately after form creation and also not make it visible in doing so?

Comment: Please provide minimal code to demonstrate issue.

Comment: @MarcusAdams to be fair, there's not really any code to show here.  Make a TPopupMenu, fill it with a large number of items, and observe that it takes longer to open the first time.  The items are obviously ending up in a cache once they are generated in the first instance.

Comment: @J..., see, you've already spent your time eliminating the tree view as the problem. No need to address me if you want to do the OPs work for them, just do it. By the way, how many is a "large" number and how much of a delay are we talking about?

Comment: @MarcusAdams There is no large number of items... Just place a tree view with 5-7 items and link all of them with a TPopupMenu with a single item. Run it and right click any of the tree items and voila!

Comment: @MarcusAdams I don't think I've eliminated the treeview as the issue, I'm just saying that showing code is not necessarily applicable to this problem.  That's not to say that OP doesn't need to clarify, but rather that asking for code is perhaps not the type of clarification we need.

Comment: What Delphi version? I just followed your exact steps (up to #4, where I simply linked the popup menu to the entire treeview instead of to the six individual items), and running and right-clicking was almost instantaneous every time including the first. I tested with XE5, update 2.

Comment: @KenWhite I have delphi xe3 update 2. I have observed the delay with a single TPopup in xe3 and in xe4 when more than one are attached.

Comment: OK, so this is an issue with an earlier version of FMX. It's apparently been improved/fixed in a later one.